# Using vba, is it possible to open multiple Excel workbooks from the same folder and keep them open at the same time?

Tags: excel, vba

This is not the first time I ask this question, but I have slightly altered the details to hopefully make it clearer. Here is one version of the code I have tried:

```
Private Sub OpenWbsInPath(zPath As String)
Dim zFile As String
zPath = IIf(Right$(zPath, 1) = "\", zPath, zPath & "\")   ' Ensure zPath ends with "\".
zFile = Dir(zPath & "*.xls*")                             ' "xxxx\*.xls*". OK.
Do While zFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=zPath & zFile      ' Fails with error 1004 on 2nd iteration.
    DoEvents                                    ' Makes no difference.
    zFile = Dir()                               ' Next filename. Path also OK.
Loop
End Sub
```

I have also tried a similar procedure using `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`. In all approaches I have tried so far, including one in which I created an array of file names first and then tried to open each file individually, the first file opens OK, then the next file fails to open with error 1004.
The really strange thing is that in an older version of the program, all the files open OK. I have even tried copying the identical code, but it still doesn't work in the new location. I am running out of ideas - do I need to create a temporary folder for each workbook before I open it? Seems crazy.

Comment: I've run your code, and can confirm it works fine, _if_ the files can be opened, and fails with error 1004 if they can't.   Possible reasons that a file can't be opened include: it's corrupt, or it's already open. A file can be open if: you or your code opened it (is the file containing the code also in the folder?), someone else has it open (is the folder shared?), another instance of Excel has it open (check task manager for extra instances).  Can you manually open the file the code fails on? Add a `Debug.Print zFile` before the Open to see what file fails

Comment: Many thanks. To answer your questions: I don't think the files are corrupt, I can open them manually with no trouble. The files that don't open are not already open: only the first file was opened. The file to be opened are in a sub-folder of the file that contains the code - I have wondered if this might be an issue but can find nothing about it. It is not a shared network - just my own computer. I will check task manager but do not believe there is another instance open. The file that fails is the next correct file in the folder to be opened.

Comment: On reflection though, I am beginning to think it must be *something* about the files, rather than the code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, just to be sure: did you identify the specific file that failed to open, and can you open that file manually? When you manually open it does it open normally,  or read only, or fail to open?

Comment: It is definitely something about the files.  Like I said, the code works fine, _if_ the files can open

Comment: You were right! One of the files was corrupt. Not a coding issue at all. I had thought I becoming senile!

Comment: Glad you solved it.  I'll add my first comment as an answer so we can close this out

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code, and can confirm it works fine, if the files can be opened, and fails with error 1004 if they can't.

Possible reasons that a file can't be opened include

1. it's corrupt, or.
2. it's already open.

A file can't be open if:

1. you or your code opened it already (is the file containing the code also in the folder?),
2. someone else has it open (is the folder shared?),
3. another instance of Excel has it open (check task manager for extra instances).

Can you manually open the file the code fails on? Add a Debug.Print zFile before the Open to see what file fails